# passing struct member to function in c

Tags: c, struct

I have this file and input it as array of struct in c.
However I have problem in passing the struct member to the function.
Error: Not even a pointer or an array value has been with the subscript in line 58.
I am a newbie in c and stuck with this problem for a week.

The codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct list{
  int counter;
  int year;
  double maxrain;
  double rank;
} data;

double avg (struct list s, int count);

int main()
{
  data a[SIZE];
  struct list s;
  double sum = 0;
  int totalFile = 1;        // according to number of csv file
  int z, i;
  char fName[16];
  FILE*fpt;

  double mean;

  /* reading multiple file */
  for (z=1; z<=totalFile; z++)
  {
    sprintf(fName," ",z);
    fpt = fopen(fName,"r");

    if(fpt == NULL){
      printf("Error opening %s\n",fName);
      return(-1);
    }

    printf("---Reading from file %d---\n", z);
    sum = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(i <= SIZE && fscanf(fpt, "%d%*c%d%*c%f%*c%f", &a[i].counter, &a[i].year, &a[i].maxrain, &a[i].rank) != EOF){
      sum = sum + a[i].maxrain;
      i++;  
    }
    mean = avg(a[i].maxrain, i);
    printf("%f", mean);

    return 0;
  }
}

double avg(struct list s , int count)
{
  double ave;
  int i = 0;

  for(i=0; i<count; add += s.maxrain[i++]);
  ave = add/count;

  return ave;
}
```

Comment: Does &(a[i].counter) work? And so on ...

Comment: Experts here will tell you the error by just looking at the code. But , still you must let us know which is line **58**

Comment: "Error: Not even a pointer or an array value has been with the subscript in line 58." — this doesn't sound like something a compiler would say. Copy paste please.

Comment: Please indent code before posting it on this site. If you write your code in a code editor, it wouldn't be a problem - decent code editors replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: @Lundin or vice versa :)

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues here to which you would have been pointed by the compiler, if you'd have told the compiler to tell you the maximunm of possible warnings. For gcc the options to do so are `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

But now for the issues en detail:

Here

```
sprintf(fName, " ", z);
```

the conversion specifier is missing. The code should look like this:

```
sprintf(fName, "%d", z);
```

Also [sprintf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) is unsave as it might overflow the destination "string". Use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) instead:

```
snprintf(fName, "%d", sizeof(fName), z);
```

---

The following scan command uses `%f` which expected float, but has `double` being passed in.

```
fscanf(fpt, "%d%*c%d%*c%f%*c%f", &a[i].counter, &a[i].year, &a[i].maxrain, &a[i].rank)
```

Use `%lf` to scan doubles:

```
fscanf(fpt, "%d%*c%d%*c%lf%*c%lf", &a[i].counter, &a[i].year, &a[i].maxrain, &a[i].rank)
```

---

This

```
mean = avg(a[i].maxrain, i);
```

should be

```
mean = avg(a[i], i);
```

---

And finally the declaration/definition of `add` is missing in `avg()`.

---

As a note on declaring variables to server as array index:

Array indicies are always positive, so it does not make sense to use a signed variable for this.

Also it is uncertain how wide the one or the other integer types is, so it is not save to use every to address memory. To stay on the save side when addressing array elements (and with this memory) use `size_t`, which is guaranteed by the C Standard to be an unsigned integere wide enough to address all of the machine's memory (and with this the maximum possible array element).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Passing elements of struct to function:**

```
main() {
    struct list data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    avg(data.counter, data.year, data.maxrain, data.rank, 5);
}

double avg(int counter, int year, double maxrain, double rank, int count) {
    //    
}
```

**2. Passing struct to function**

```
main() {
    struct list data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    avg(data, 5);
}

double avg(struct list s , int count) {
    //    
}
```

**3. Passing address of struct to function with pointer**

```
main() {
    struct list data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    avg(&data, 5);
}

double avg(struct list *s , int count) {
    //    
}
```